# Mysql Sequelize: group by select row where age is max

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with id, age (timestamp) and value.

```
 ---------------------------------
| id | age | value | type | pass |
 ---------------------------------
```

I want to select one value based on max(age) for each type. I tried the following Sequelize, but cannot get the value. Value is string message. Pass is password for the user.

```
Key.findAll({
      where: {
        pass: password,
      },
      group: ['t'],
      attributes: ["t", [Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('age')), 'age'], ],
      
    });
```

How to get the value of selected max age row for each value type?

Comment: How can age be a timestamp?

Comment: I have defined it that way in model. It is Creation Timestamp named age.